# Moving scripts into a separate file in gitlab-ci.yml to avoid code duplication and including it from several files

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to set up a CI with minimal code duplication using **.gitlab-ci.yml**.

With that, I am separating the configuration in separate files and reusing parts of it that are common.

I have a separate repository with Gitlab CI settings: *gitlab-ci* and several projects that use it to form their own CI pipelines.

### Contents of gitlab-ci repository

#### template_jobs.yml:

```yaml
.sample:
  rules:
    -  if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
       when: on_success
    -  when: never
```

#### jobs_architectureA.yml:

```yaml
include:
  - local: '/template_jobs.yml'

.script_core: &script_core
  -  echo "Running stage"

test_archA:
  extends:
    - .sample
  stage: test
  tags:
    - architectureA
  script:
    - *script_core
```

#### jobs_architectureB.yml:

```yaml
include:
  - local: '/template_jobs.yml'

.script_core: &script_core
  -  echo "Running stage"

test_archB:
  extends:
    - .sample
  stage: test
  tags:
    - architectureB
  script:
    - *script_core
```

### Project with code contents:

In the actual project (separate repositories per project, and I have a lot of them), I have the following:

#### .gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
stages:
  - test

include:
  - project: 'gitlab-ci'
    file: '/jobs_architectureA.yml'
  - project: 'gitlab-ci'
    file: '/jobs_architectureB.yml'
```

This configuration works fine and allows to include only some architectures for some modules while sharing rules between the job templates.

However, it's easy to notice one code duplication: both **jobs_architectureA.yml** and **jobs_architectureB.yml** contain a common section:

```yaml
.script_core: &script_core
  -  echo "Running stage"
```

It would be ideal to move it into a separate file: **template_scripts.yml** and include from both *jobs_architectureA.yml** and **jobs_architectureB.yml**. However, that results in the invalid YAML (at least from Gitlab's point of view).

With that, I make a conclusion that I can share the rules as the mechanism of their usage is via `extends` keyword; however, I am not able to do it with the scripts: as it uses `&`/`*`  *anchor*ing mechanic on the YAML level.

Ideally, I want something along the lines of:

### Contents of the ideal (conceptually) gitlab-ci repository

#### template_jobs.yml:

```yaml
.sample:
  rules:
    -  if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
       when: on_success
    -  when: never
```

#### template_scripts.yml:

```yaml
.script_core: &script_core
  -  echo "Running stage"
```

#### jobs_architectureA.yml:

```yaml
include:
  - local: '/template_jobs.yml'
  - local: '/template_scripts.yml'

test_archA:
  extends:
    - .sample
  stage: test
  tags:
    - architectureA
  script:
    - *script_core  # this becomes invalid, as script_core is in the other file, even though it is included at the top
```

#### jobs_architectureB.yml:

```yaml
include:
  - local: '/template_jobs.yml'
  - local: '/template_scripts.yml'

test_archB:
  extends:
    - .sample
  stage: test
  tags:
    - architectureB
  script:
    - *script_core # this becomes invalid, as script_core is in the other file, even though it is included at the top
```

---

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Am I hitting a limitation of the Gitlab mechanic? Is it the implementation of the `include` directive in this specific YML type, that limits me?
- Do I have options to achieve something close to the desired behaviour?

---

Note, while this might not look like a big deal, in reality, I have many more pieces to the scripts, and the actual script is much larger. Thus, currently, it is duplicated code all over the place which is very prone to mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

my solution is to not include `template_jobs.yml` and `template_scripts.yml` directly in `jobs_architectureA.yml` but only in the "final" .gitlab-ci.yml

taking you exemple, `/template_jobs.yml`/`/template_scripts.yml` do not change.

`jobs_architectureA.yml` loses the `include`:

```
test_archA:
  extends:
    - .sample
  stage: test
  tags:
    - architectureB
  script:
    - *script_core # this becomes invalid, as script_core is in the other file, even though it is included at the top
```

and `.gitlab-ci.yml` becomes:

```
stages:
  - test

include:
  - local: '/template_jobs.yml'
  - local: '/template_scripts.yml'
  - project: 'gitlab-ci'
    file: '/jobs_architectureA.yml'
  - project: 'gitlab-ci'
    file: '/jobs_architectureB.yml'
```

Comment: interesting. I have to try if that works (actually, why is that any different?). However, that significantly limits the ability to do customization already on the _.gitlab-ci.yml_ level, if one wants to define a custom stage and job here using templates.

Answer (score 2):

> in reality, I have many more pieces to the scripts, and the actual script is much larger

Adding to [Cyril](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5724705/cyril-jouve)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64722006/6309), [GitLab 13.12](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/05/22/gitlab-13-12-released/#support-wildcards-when-including-yaml-cicd-configuration-files) (May 2021) can help scale those includes:

> ### Support wildcards when including YAML CI/CD configuration files
>
> The `includes:` keyword for CI/CD pipelines lets you break one long `.gitlab-ci.yml` file into multiple smaller files to increase readability.
> It also makes it easier to reuse configuration in multiple places.
>
> Frequently there are multiple files included into a single pipeline, and they all might be stored in the same place.
>
> In this release, we add support to use the `*` wildcard with the local `includes:` keyword. You can now make your `includes:` sections more dynamic, less verbose, and easier to read, check out how we are [dogfooding](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/commit/f0629cc5eaa70a29cb2d98e5e1e0915d4968840e) it in GitLab.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_12/wildcard1.png -- Support wildcards when including YAML CI/CD configuration files]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#includelocal-with-wildcard-file-paths) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/25921).

Answer (score 0):

The `extends:` keyword can be used with multiple jobs to extend from (on recent versions of GitLab). You can simply do the following:

```
include:
  - local: '/template_jobs.yml'

.script_core:
  -  echo "Running stage"
 
test_archA:
  extends:
    - .sample
    - .script_core
  stage: test
  tags:
    - architectureA
```

And after that move the `.script_core` to an import.